# How to specify annotation set ID when calling import_data on google vertex ImageDataset

Tags: google-ai-platform

I'm working on a system to gather some training images and upload them automatically into a Vertex AI image object detection dataset.   I've saved the files into a google cloud storage bucket along with a jsonl file with labels and bounding boxes.  I've noticed if I import the JSON file through the vertex console on the web then everything is fine and the images are added to the dataset along with their bounding boxes.

When I add them with the API I first thought there were no bounding boxes, but on closer inspection I can see that when I use the vertex console the bounding boxes are there with all the existing ones in the annotation set called 'my_dataset_iod', but when I add through the API I am inadvertently creating a new Annotation set called something like 'my_dataset_image_bounding_box_2023_09_19_080419'.   I can also see that there is an ID for 'my_dataset_iod' in the url line - annotationSetId=1197.....  - but I can't figure out how to tell the import_data command that this is the annotation set I want to use.

Here's my code for reference

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import aiplatform
.....
        current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
        jsonl_file_name = f"data_{current_datetime}.jsonl"
        jsonl_blob = bucket.blob(jsonl_file_name)
        jsonl_blob.upload_from_string(jsonl_string, content_type='application/jsonl')
        dataset = aiplatform.ImageDataset(f"projects/{project_id}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{dataset_id}")
        dataset.import_data( gcs_source=[f"gs://{bucket_name}/{jsonl_file_name}"], import_schema_uri='gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/image_bounding_box_io_format_1.0.0.yaml')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import data into a **Vertex AI Image Object Detection Dataset** using the API, you want the imported data to be associated with an existing annotation set rather than creating a new one. To do this, you need to specify the **annotation set ID** when using the `import_data` command.

```
# Specify the import data configuration, including the annotation_set_name
import_data_config = {
    "gcs_source": {"uris": [f"gs://{bucket_name}/{jsonl_file_name}"]},
    "annotation_schema": {"annotation_set_name": f"projects/{project_id}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{dataset_id}/annotationSets/{annotation_set_id}"},
    "import_schema_uri": "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/image_bounding_box_io_format_1.0.0.yaml"
}
```

We explicitly set the `annotation_set_name` in the `annotation_schema` to point to the existing annotation set using its resource name. This way, you can ensure that the imported data is associated with the correct annotation set.

This workaround could help you or give you an idea.